# Lightning Quick Action that sets checkbox as true

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience

So I currently have a checkbox which when checked (set true) it kicks off a workflow. What I would like is to have a Lightning Quick action when clicked to set this check box as true. However, I have not found anything about this online so I am wondering if this is even possible.

Comment: Do you want to set checkbox on an SObject record, custom settings record or custom metadata record?

Comment: It will be on a record. The checkbox is a field within a custom object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example provides details how to perform custom object record save using [Lightning Data Service.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_example.htm)

You can modify it to meet your needs.

1. You need a custom object record attribute.

   <aura:attribute name="newContact" type="Object" access="private"/>
   <aura:attribute name="simpleNewContact" type="Object" access="private"/>
2. You need force:recordData tag.

   <force:recordData aura:id="contactRecordCreator"
       layoutType="FULL"
       targetRecord="{!v.newContact}"
       targetFields="{!v.simpleNewContact}"
       targetError="{!v.newContactError}"
       />
3. You need to display input for checkbox field

   <lightning:input aura:id="contactField" name="CustomCheckbox__c" label="Custom checkox" value="{!v.simpleNewContact.CustomCheckbox__c}"/>
4. You need cancel and save button

   <lightning:button label="Cancel" onclick="{!c.handleCancel}" class="slds-m-top_medium" />

Also you need handleSaveContact and handleCancel methods in javascript controller.

Simplest version to save record would be just

```
handleSaveContact: function(component, event, helper) {
    component.find("contactRecordCreator").saveRecord();
},

handleCancel: function(component, event, helper) {
    $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
}
```

That's if you don't care about processing result. If you don't care if save operation has succeeded or failed. If you need to process update result you might need extra code shown below.

```
handleSaveContact: function(component, event, helper) {
    component.find("contactRecordCreator").saveRecord(function(saveResult) {
            if (saveResult.state === "SUCCESS" || saveResult.state === "DRAFT") {

                // Success! Prepare a toast UI message
                var resultsToast = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                resultsToast.setParams({
                    "title": "Contact Saved",
                    "message": "The new contact was created."
                });

                // Update the UI: close panel, show toast, refresh account page
                $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
                resultsToast.fire();

                // Reload the view so components not using force:recordData
                // are updated
                $A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();
            }
            else if (saveResult.state === "INCOMPLETE") {
                console.log("User is offline, device doesn't support drafts.");
            }
            else if (saveResult.state === "ERROR") {
                console.log('Problem saving contact, error: ' +
                             JSON.stringify(saveResult.error));
            }
            else {
                console.log('Unknown problem, state: ' + saveResult.state +
                            ', error: ' + JSON.stringify(saveResult.error));
            }
        );
},

handleCancel: function(component, event, helper) {
    $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
}
```

Comment: Is all this needed just to have a quick action set a checkbox as true?

Comment: There are several ways: you can achieve this using Apex Controller or without, I provided a simplest way how to achieve this without using Apex Controller. Do you prefer or are you interested in Apex Controller solution approach?

Comment: An approach without a controller is better in my opinion. I am just a little surprised that it requires a lot of code. But you have explained it very clearly so thank you

Comment: I mean: most of the code is actually auxiliary - I can refactor my answer to highlight required part

Comment: So you only need line component.find("contactRecordCreator").saveRecord(); to save record. But if you need to process save operation result then you would need extra code

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed and well explained answer.